# spark reduceByKeyAndWindow window have error interval

Tags: apache-spark, sliding-window

I use stream 2.1 spark 1.6 scala program, the partial code is listed below.
Follow documentation saying that window size 3 and sliding size 2 and then windowed stream will appear at time 3 and time 5 but I got at time 4 and time 6 but windows size 3 and sliding size 1 is OK.

```
val inputData: mutable.Queue[RDD[String]] = mutable.Queue() 
var outputCollector = new ArrayBuffer[(String, Int)] 

val inputStream = ssc.queueStream(inputData) 

val patternStream: DStream[(String, Int)] = inputStream.flatMap(line => { 
  line.replace(",", "").map(x => (x.toString(), 1)) 
}) 

val groupStream = patternStream.reduceByKeyAndWindow(_+_, _-_, Seconds(wt1), Seconds(st1)) 

inputStream.print() 

patternStream.foreachRDD(rdd=>{ 
  rdd.collect().foreach(print) 
  println("\n") 
}) 


groupStream.foreachRDD(rdd => { 
  println("window stream") 
  rdd.filter(s => s._2>0).sortByKey().collect().foreach(i=> {outputCollector += (i)} ) 
})
```

### window size 3 sliding size 1 it is ok

### Time: 1000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(b,1)(f,1)(g,1)

### Time: 2000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(b,1)(d,1)(e,1)(f,1)(g,1)

### Time: 3000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(b,1)(c,1)(d,2)(e,1)(f,1)(g,1)

### Time: 4000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(c,1)(d,3)(e,1)

### Time: 5000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(c,2)(d,3)

### Time: 6000 ms

window stream (a,2)(c,2)(d,2)(f,1)(g,1)

window size 3  slice size 2

### window stream appear in 2 4 6 have some error

### Time: 1000 ms

---

### Time: 2000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(b,1)(d,1)(e,1)(f,1)(g,1)

### Time: 3000 ms

### ##############  no widowed streamhere

### Time: 4000 ms

### window stream (a,1)(c,1)(d,3)(e,1)

### Time: 5000 ms

### ############    no widowed stream here

### Time: 6000 ms

window stream (a,2)(c,2)(d,2)(f,1)(g,1)

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: My question is the window size have no effect, in document window length 3 sliding 2, the window rdds will be generated at time 3 and time 5, but I try (window size, sliding size) 32 42 52 the window rdds always are generated at time 2 and time 4 ..., and I try 33 43 53 and I have window rdds are generated at time 3 and time 6 ...., so the window length have no effect. any help